# Load fixtures one time before all phpunit test on symfony 3

Tags: performance, symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit, fixtures

I ve got a SF3 application and lot of functionnals tests.
Before each tests we load and purge all fixtures.
Time of all tests are so long. 
I would like to load fixtures just one time et truncate after last test.

Is it the good method to improve functionnal tests speed ?

Is there a php method in phpunit which is launched just one time before all tests ? (Because setUpBeforeClass is executed before each test)

An exemple of the setUpBeforeClass method in my test's classes.

```
class SearchRegisterControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /** @var Client $client */
    private $client;

    protected static $application;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        $kernel = static::createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();

        $em = $kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
        $schemaTool = new SchemaTool($em);
        $metadata = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();

        $schemaTool->dropSchema($metadata);
        $schemaTool->createSchema($metadata);

        /** @var Client $client */
        $client = static::createClient();
        $em = $client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');

        $loader = new Loader();

        $loader->loadFromDirectory('src/MyNameSpace/AppBundle/DataFixtures/ORM');

        $purger = new ORMPurger();
        $executor = new ORMExecutor($em, $purger);
        $executor->execute($loader->getFixtures(), true);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You could implement [a test listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.examples.SimpleTestListener.php).

<kbd>tests/StartTestSuiteListener.php</kbd>

```
namespace App\Tests;



class StartTestSuite extends \PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener
{
    public function startTestSuite(\PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {
      // do initial stuff
    }

}
```

Then enable  [enable the test listener](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.test-listeners) in your `phpunit.xml` config:

<kbd>phpunit.xml</kbd>

```
<phpunit
 ...
>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="App\Tests\StartTestSuiteListener">
        </listener>
    </listeners>
[...]
</phpunit>
```

In the same manner you could implement a endTestSuite (Check for all event listed in the doc)

Hope this help

Comment: how do you inject service in this listener ? ContainerAwareInterface doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 2):

You can use bash script like this to load fixtures once before all tests.

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --env=test --if-not-exists
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --env=test --complete
php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load --fixtures=tests/fixtures/api --env=test --no-interaction
php vendor/bin/phpunit tests/Functional
```

Keep in mind that your test will not be executed within isolated environments with fresh data and thus will interfere with each other.

Comment: Good, but I find if cleaner to do schema:drop/create/validate.